# Raycast detects all object, but not all objects take damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object-detection, game-physics, raycasting

When the player presses Q, it creates a ball. The more time you press Q, the ball gets bigger and bigger.

This is the problem: If the ball is small, after the explosion, raycast detect nearby enemies and deal damage (if they are inside the explosion radius), but, as the ball gets bigger and bigger, raycast detect enemies but doesn't deal any damage to them. (I use spherecast and then I send a raycast to every object that is inside the radius)

[Small ball explosion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPg0Q.png)
[Small ball explosion, detects all of the enemies and deals damage to some of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOWJb.png)
[big ball explosion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1fom.png)
[big ball explosion, detects all of the enemies and deals damage to none of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OncmR.png)

New info: [Here you can see radius before explision. After explosion 4 of enemies got detected, but only 2 of them got damaged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg8hE.jpg)

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class BULLET : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] float countDown;
    [SerializeField] int Maxhits = 25;
    bool destroyy = false;
    public float Radius = 10f;
    //[SerializeField] LayerMask HitLayer;
    public float explosiveForce;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask BlockExplo;
    private Collider[] Hits;
    bool wallHit = false;
    [SerializeField] float x, y, z;
    [SerializeField] GameObject posRay;
    [SerializeField] GameObject Ps_Explose;
    [SerializeField] float MaxDamage;
    [SerializeField] float MinDamage;

    private void Start()
    {
        Hits = new Collider[Maxhits]
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        countDown -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (destroyy || countDown <= 0)
        {
            int hits = Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(posRay.transform.position, Radius, Hits);

            GameObject PS = Instantiate(Ps_Explose, transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
            PS.transform.localScale = gameObject.transform.localScale * 1.5f;
            // print("" + transform.position);

            for (int i = 0; i < hits; i++)
            {
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(posRay.transform.position, Hits[i].transform.position - transform.position))
                {
                    if (Hits[i].TryGetComponent<Rigidbody>(out Rigidbody rigidbody))
                    {
                        float distance = Vector3.Distance(posRay.transform.position, Hits[i].transform.position);

                        if (Physics.Raycast(posRay.transform.position + new Vector3(x, y, z), (Hits[i].transform.position - transform.position), out hit))
                        {
                            Debug.DrawLine(posRay.transform.position + new Vector3(x, y, z), (Hits[i].transform.position), Color.red);

                            if (hit.transform.tag != "Walls")
                            {
                                print("No wall");
                                rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(explosiveForce, transform.position, Radius);
                                if (hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
                                    hit.transform.GetComponent<EnemyHp>().enemyHp -= Mathf.FloorToInt(Mathf.Lerp(MaxDamage, MinDamage, distance / Radius));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                print("WALLLLL " + hit.transform.position + hit.transform.name);
                                //return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.transform.tag == ("Walls") || other.gameObject.transform.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            destroyy = true;
        }
    }


    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position, Radius);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the radius?

Comment: Yes.  Bigger ball = bigger radius. Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q) --> ( BulletThrow.GetComponent<BULLET>().Radius += Time.deltaTime * 2.2f;)

Comment: If I am right, there is a problem with te radius. I remove this part of code  other.GetComponent<EnemyHp>().enemyHp -= 200; and the object that gets hit, it only gets damage if the radius is small, otherwise it doesnt get any damage

Comment: No. That gives you 200 damage when triggered. Id say the most likely issue is the keep between max and min. Which values you haven’t shared.

Comment: You might have meant while triggered? Maybe. Not just when it hits.

Comment: yes, i meant triggerd. I am going to share max and min. Max = 300 and min = 1

Comment: Right so if it’s on the radius it’s getting 1 damage. Woo. If you meant to take 200 while triggered not just as it goes past then you need a different method.

Comment: I deleted 200 damage ontrigger. Object now get damage depending on radius. I upload some extra photoes. Maybe they help us. Bottom right of the screen you can see enemy Hp

Comment: Is there a reason you have two separate line of sight checks? And to check that you've hit the right enemy, you could just do `if (hit.transform.gameObject == Hits[i])`

Comment: You are right i didnt need 2 of them so i deleted the first one. Next i check if there are any walls because i dont want covered enemies to get damage

Comment: I am almost sure that the problem is inside raycast and radius because if radius is big, enemy doesnt take any damage but otherwise he takes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found out how i can do it to work. This part of code should be changed into

```
  if (Hits[i].TryGetComponent<Rigidbody>(out Rigidbody rigidbody))
            {
                float distance = Vector3.Distance(posRay.transform.position, Hits[i].transform.position);




                if (Physics.Raycast(posRay.transform.position + new Vector3(x, y, z), (Hits[i].transform.position - transform.position), out hit))
                {
                    Debug.DrawLine(posRay.transform.position + new Vector3(x, y, z), (Hits[i].transform.position), Color.red);

                    if (hit.transform.tag != "Walls")
                    {

                        print("No wall");
                        rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(explosiveForce, transform.position, Radius);
                        if (hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
                            hit.transform.GetComponent<EnemyHp>().enemyHp -= Mathf.FloorToInt(Mathf.Lerp(MaxDamage, MinDamage, distance / Radius));
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        print("WALLLLL " + hit.transform.position + hit.transform.name);
                        //return;
                    }



                    //  }
                }

            }
```

This one

```
  if (Hits[i].TryGetComponent<Rigidbody>(out Rigidbody rigidbody))
                {
                    float distance = Vector3.Distance(posRay.transform.position, Hits[i].transform.position);




                    if (Physics.Raycast(posRay.transform.position , (Hits[i].transform.position - transform.position).normalized, out hit))
                    {
                        Debug.DrawLine(posRay.transform.position, (Hits[i].transform.position ), Color.red);

                    
                            if (Hits[i].transform.CompareTag("Enemy"))
                        {
                             
                        if (Physics.Raycast(Hits[i].transform.position,  (transform.position - Hits[i].transform.position).normalized, out hit))
                            if(hit.transform.tag != "Walls")
                            {
                                rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(explosiveForce, transform.position, Radius);
                                Hits[i].transform.GetComponent<EnemyHp>().enemyHp -= Mathf.FloorToInt(Mathf.Lerp(MaxDamage, MinDamage, distance / Radius));
                            }
                          
                        }
                              
                     



                        //  }
                    }

                }
```